# How to call a prop function inside useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

Im triying to remove this warning on a react component

```
Line 19:8:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'handleChange'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

this is the component

```
const SelectButton = (props)=>{
    const [activeState, setActiveState] = useState(false)
    const label = props.label
    
    const handleClick = () =>{
        setActiveState(!activeState)
        //props.handleChange(label,activeState)
    }

    const handleChange = props.handleChange
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        handleChange(label,activeState)
    }, [label,activeState])

    return(
        <button 
                type="button" 
                onClick={handleClick} 
                className={"container-form-button "+(activeState?"active":"")}>
                    {label}
        </button>
    )
}
```

if i tried to remove the comments on handleChange inside of handleClick, handleChange didn´t works correctly

if i tried to change useEffect for something like this

```
useEffect(()=>{
   handleChange(label,activeState)
}, [label,activeState,handleChange])
```

or

```
useEffect(()=>{
       props.handleChange(label,activeState)
    }, [label,activeState,props.handleChange])
```

it try to reder to many times and throw this error.

```
Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render
```

Actually it works like first code, but im still having the warning

this is the parent original handleChange

```
const handleChange = (name,value)=>{
        setSelected({...selected, [name]:value})
    }
```

the parentComponent

```
const CategorySearcher = (props) =>{
const ciudades = ["Guadalajara","Zapopan","Tlajomulco"]
const tipos = ["Casa","Departamento"]

const [selected, setSelected] = useState({})

const handleChange = useCallback(
    (label,value) => {
            setSelected({...selected, [label]:value})
        },
    [selected],
)
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(selected);
}, [selected])

const cities = ciudades.map((city)=><SelectButton key={city} handleChange={handleChange} label={city}/>)

const types = tipos.map((tipo)=><SelectButton key={tipo} handleChange={handleChange} label={tipo}/>)

let history = useHistory();

const setUrlSearch = ()=>{
    let urlSearch = "search/q="
    let attToSearch = []
    for (var key in selected) {
        selected[key]?attToSearch.push(key):console.log("Nada")
    }
    /*
    attToSearch.forEach((it)=>{
        urlSearch = urlSearch+"&"+it
    })*/
    console.log(urlSearch);
    history.push(urlSearch+attToSearch)
}

return (
    <section className="general-container">
        <div className="container-box">
            <span className="container_title">
                Tu nuevo hogar esta aquí :)
            </span>
        </div>
        
        <div className="container-form">
            <form className="container-form-box">
                <div className="container-form-cities">
                    <div className="container-form-subtitle">
                    Ciudades
                    </div>
                    <div className="container-buttons">
                        {cities}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="container-form-cities">
                    <div className="container-form-subtitle">Tipo de hogar</div>
                    <div className="container-buttons">
                        {types}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="container-box-button">
                    <button className="button-form-CTA" onClick={setUrlSearch}>
                        Buscar
                    </button>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
)
```

}

Comment: Why are you calling the prop inside a useEffect?

Comment: it comes from an upper component

const handleChange = (name,value)=>{
        setSelected({...selected, [name]:value})
    }

Comment: But that's not _why_?

Comment: when i change the active state i want to update the upper values

Comment: Why not call the `handleChange` inside the function `handleClick`? You've already commented it out. It shouldn't need to be inside a useEffect.

Comment: i tried but it works rarely and didnt give the correct result

Comment: I also think you should be calling it from your click handler instead, no need fo useEffect. Also, seems strange you need to pass label to the handleChange callback if the parent component already has access to the label.

Answer (score 2):

<s>You should be wrapping your function with the useCallback hook before passing it as a prop. Documentation can be found [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback).</s>

You shouldn't be using useEffect like that.

```
const SelectButton = ({ label, handleChange }) => {
  const [activeState, setActiveState] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    const newState = !activeState
    setActiveState(newState);
    handleChange(label, newState);
  };

  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={handleClick}
      className={"container-form-button " + (activeState ? "active" : "")}
    >
      {label}
    </button>
  );
};
```

Comment: im trying but didnt works, maybe im wrong writting. Do you have any example?

Comment: can you post the component you are defining the callback in?

Comment: yep, its the "parent component"

Comment: oof that is some pretty messy code. You do in fact have a loop, as made obvious by the useCallback hook.

Comment: What is the best way to writte that useCallback?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you destructure `label` and `handleChange` from props?  Check out this sandbox, this does not cause any infinite update loop: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-field-ju0wy?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const handleChange = () => console.log("handling change");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SelectButton label="Label" handleChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}

const SelectButton = ({ label, handleChange }) => {
  const [activeState, setActiveState] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setActiveState(!activeState);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    handleChange(label, activeState);
  }, [label, activeState, handleChange]);

  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={handleClick}
      className={"container-form-button " + (activeState ? "active" : "")}
    >
      {label}
    </button>
  );
};
```

Comment: Please may you put the code in the answer? Link only answers are not helpful when the linked site disappears, or goes down.

Comment: Sorry, but it still try to reder to many times on react console

Comment: Try this on sandbox
export default function App() {
  const [selected,setSelected] = React.useState({})
  const handleChange = (name,value)=>{ setSelected({...selected, [name]:value}) }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SelectButton label="Label" handleChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}